# Selecting a record based on a series of criteria

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I would like to run a query that will allow me to chose the best record from a particular username based on certain criteria.  I have 2 columns (col01, col02) that are my criteria that I am looking at.

•   If one record (username a in the example below) has both columns as yes, I would like that one to take precedence.

•   If one record has col01 as a yes, that takes next 2nd rank precenence (username c in the example below)

•   If one record has col01, and the other has col02 as yes, than col01 takes precedence(username d in the example below).

•   If one record has col02 as yes, and the other records as no, than column two takes 3rd precedence (username g in the example below).

•   If both records are the same, than neither should be returned as these records need to be investigated further (usernames b, e, f)

Below is example sample and output. How it can be done using sql query?

```
+----------+-----+-------+-------+
| username | id  | col01 | col02 |
+----------+-----+-------+-------+
| a        | 1  | yes    | yes   |
| a        | 2  | yes    | no    |
| b        | 3  | no     | no    |
| b        | 4  | no     | no    |
| c        | 5  | yes    | no    |
| c        | 6  | no     | no    |
| d        | 7  | yes    | no    |
| d        | 8  | no     | yes   |
| e        | 9  | no     | yes   |
| e        | 10 | no     | yes   |
| f        | 11 | yes    | yes   |
| f        | 12 | yes    | yes   |
| g        | 13 | no     | no    |
| g        | 14 | no     | yes   |
+----------+----+--------+-------+
```

output

```
+----------+-----+-------+------+
| username | id  | col01 | col02|
+----------+-----+-------+------+
| a        | 1  | yes    | yes  |
| c        | 5  | yes    | no   |
| d        | 7  | yes    | no   |
| g        | 14 | no     | yes  |
+----------+----+--------+------+
```

Edit: I was asked to explain the conditions.  Basically the records come from the same area (username); The col01 is the most recently updated information we have, while col02 is older.  Both columns are important to us, so that is why it is better if both are yes; col01 being more recent is where the more dependable data is. Where all the records are exactly the same, we have to dig a little deeper to understand out data.

Comment: Maybe add notes on each record from your data sample to explain why it was discarded \ chosen . It's hard to understand your conditions.

Comment: What about username `f`

Comment: username f has the same values for both records, so we have to look at it manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use analytic functions and then you do not need any self-joins:

**Query**:

```
SELECT username,
       id,
       col01,
       col02
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         c.col2,
         MIN( t.col01 ) OVER ( PARTITION BY username ) AS mincol01,
         MAX( t.col01 ) OVER ( PARTITION BY username ) AS maxcol01,
         MIN( c.col02 ) OVER ( PARTITION BY username ) AS mincol02,
         MAX( c.col02 ) OVER ( PARTITION BY username ) AS maxcol02,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY username
                             ORDER BY t.col01 DESC, c.col02 DESC ) AS rn
  FROM   table_name t
         INNER JOIN
         col02_table c
         ON ( t.id = c.id )
)
WHERE  ( mincol01 < maxcol01 OR mincol02 < maxcol02 )
AND    rn = 1;
```

**Output**:

```
USERNAME ID COL01 COL02
-------- -- ----- -----
a         1 yes   yes
c         5 yes   no
d         7 yes   no
g        14 no    yes
```

Comment: hello, I wanted to ask you if this can be modified.  I made an error and forgot to mention that col02 is on a different table.  Thank you.

Comment: @user7002207 Updated - just use an inner join on the two tables.

Answer (score 1):

```
with
     inputs ( username, id, col01 , col02 ) as (
       select 'a',  1, 'yes', 'yes' from dual union all
       select 'a',  2, 'yes', 'no'  from dual union all
       select 'b',  3, 'no' , 'no'  from dual union all
       select 'b',  4, 'no' , 'no'  from dual union all
       select 'c',  5, 'yes', 'no'  from dual union all
       select 'c',  6, 'no' , 'no'  from dual union all
       select 'd',  7, 'yes', 'no'  from dual union all
       select 'd',  8, 'no' , 'yes' from dual union all
       select 'e',  9, 'no' , 'yes' from dual union all
       select 'e', 10, 'no' , 'yes' from dual union all
       select 'f', 11, 'yes', 'yes' from dual union all
       select 'f', 12, 'yes', 'yes' from dual union all
       select 'g', 13, 'no' , 'no'  from dual union all
       select 'g', 14, 'no' , 'yes' from dual
     )
-- Query begins here
select   username, 
         max(id) keep (dense_rank last order by col01, col02) as id, 
         max(col01)                                           as col01,
         max(col02) keep (dense_rank last order by col01)     as col02
from     inputs
group by username
having   min(col01) != max(col01) or min(col02) != max(col02)
;



USERNAME  ID COL COL
-------- --- --- ---
a          1 yes yes
c          5 yes no 
d          7 yes no 
g         14 no  yes
```

Comment: Not sure if this will work as we have about 4500 usernames to look through; But thank you.

Comment: Why not? The query will work with 5 users or with 500,000, why do you think it won't?

Comment: I'd like to preface this by saying I am not adept at sql so I may not know what I am talking about.  I was under the assumption that we would have to manually input all the data above "--query begins here",  which is not feasible.  I apologize if I misunderstood. Does the data on the upper portion have to be manually entered?

Comment: @user7002207 - No, it doesn't. Delete all of that (the "input data" which I included just for testing purposes); the solution I propose begins below the commented line, `-- Query begins here`. You will need to substitute your actual table name in the FROM clause (instead of `inputs`), and your actual column names. If I understand correctly, you don't have just one table - that is OK, put the join in the FROM clause, and the proper column identifiers in the SELECT, GROUP BY and HAVING clauses. It should work fine.

Comment: @user7002207 -  And since you mentioned "not knowing what you are talking about" - don't worry, I am in the same boat. Very often I don't know what I am talking about either. No worries!

Comment: I appreciate the help; I will try out your query with what I am doing.

Answer (score 0):

Use multiple outer self joins, one for records with both `yes`, one for records with only col01 = `yes` and one for records with only col02 = `yes`. Then add predicates to only select records where the id is the id of the first record in that set (id of row with same name that has both `yes`, id of row with same name that has only col01 = `yes`, etc.)
to get rid of rows that are dupes, filter out any row where there's another row, (with different id) that has same value for username, col01, and col02.

```
Select distinct a.username, a.id,
    a.col01, a.col02
From table a
   left join table b   -- <- this is rows with both cols = yes
       on b.username=a.username 
          and b.col01='yes'
          and b.col02='yes' 
   left join table c1  -- <- this is rows with col1 = yes
       on c1.username=a.username 
          and c1.col01='yes'
          and c1.col02='no' 
   left join table c2  -- <- this is rows with col2 = yes         
       on c2.username=a.username 
          and c2.col01='no' 
          and c2.col02='yes'
Where a.id = coalesce(b.id, c1.Id, c2.Id)
   and not exists  -- <- This gets rid of f
      (select * from table 
       where username = a.username
          and id != a.id
          and col01 = a.col01
          and col02 = a.col02)
```

if `col02` is in another table, then in each place you use the table and need col02, you will need to add another join to this other table.

```
Select distinct a.username, a.id,
    a.col01, ot.col02
From (table a join other table ot 
          on ot.id = a.Id)
   left join (table b join otherTable ob -- <- this rows with both cols yes
                  on ob.id= b.id)
       on b.username=a.username 
          and b.col01='yes'
          and ob.col02='yes' 
   left join (table c1 join otherTable oc1  -- <- this rows with col1 yes
                  on oc1.id= c1.id)
       on c1.username=a.username 
          and c1.col01='yes'
          and oc1.col02='no' 
   left join (table c2 join otherTable oc2 -- <- this rows with col2 yes
                  on oc2.id= c2.id)         
       on c2.username=a.username 
          and c2.col01='no' 
          and oc2.col02='yes'
Where a.id = coalesce(b.id, c1.Id, c2.Id)
   and not exists  -- <- This gets rid of f
      (select * from table e
           join otherTable oe
              on oe.id= e.id
       where e.username = a.username
          and e.id != a.id
          and e.col01 = a.col01
          and oe.col02 = a.col02)
```

Comment: So I made an error; col02 is in a different table.  can I still incorporate this code somehow?

Comment: yes, you would have to join the two tables. but I can't help unless I know the relationship between the two tables.

Comment: They can be joined using the id field.  on the other table It would be something like idm

Comment: Well I added another SQL query assuming it is `id` on both tables.  If it's not you will need to edit that.  Please, next time to you submit a question, try to include the exact schema, or at least an accurate subset of that which is necessary to understand the complete problem.

Comment: no problem, good luck ! if this works, please mark it as answer.

Comment: While this may be a solution it is going to be very inefficient with that many self-joins.

Comment: That totally depends on what indices are present. In this case, an index needs to exist on `username` and (obviously) on `id`.

Comment: Even if indices exist, the solution will be very inefficient due to the numerous joins.

Comment: And, it *may* not be very inefficient. How much a query suffers from each additional join is not predictable. just as, for that matter, how much the performance hit you garner from using the Partition functionality. In both cases, there is much going on in the query processor/optimizer that is only apparent from review/analysis of the query plan. No matter what syntax you use, the problem must be solved by the processor using the same underlying join techniques that are available to it. .

Comment: I am having a little trouble getting it to work.  I wanted to ask you if the a.col02 on the second and last lines needed to be changed to something else as I am getting an 'invalid identifier' error. Thank you.

Comment: IN first line, was mistake which I just corrected, but You said `col02` was in some other table. That's what the query processor is looking for it.  What is this other tables' name? Wherever you see `otherTable`, replace it with the actual other table name.